# Criteria hibernate inner join projection group by

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, group-by, projection

I`m having some trouble translating this SQL to Hibernate Criteria. I have seached it for some time, but couldnt get any ideas as how to do it.

```
SELECT *  FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT tableA_nr AS cod, max(tableA_status) as sit
  FROM tableA 
  GROUP BY (tableA_nr)
 ) status_nr_list
ON a.tableA_nr = status_nr_list.cod and a.tableA_status = status_nr_list.sit
ORDER BY tableA_nr;
```

Here´s what I´ve accomplished so far.

```
criteria.setProjection(
         Projections.projectionList()
           .add(Projections.groupProperty("tableA_nr"))
           .add(Projections.max("tableA_status.id")));
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this works but the hint is you can use [Detached Criteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries) for subquery.

Sub query

```
DetachedCriteria status_nr_list = DetachedCriteria.forClass(tableA_nr.class, "tableA_nr");
status_nr_list.setProjection(Projections.max("tableA_status"));
status_nr_list.setProjection(Projections.property("tableA_nr"));
```

Main query

```
session.createCriteria(tableA_nr.class)
.add( Subqueries.propertyIn("tableA_nr", status_nr_list) )
.add( Subqueries.propertyIn("tableA_status", status_nr_list) );
```